# Getting exception when trying to generate Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-karaf

I'm trying to generate a report with Jasper Reports 5.6.0 but I always end up getting two exceptions of the following sort:

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: javax.swing.JEditorPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=,disabledTextColor=,editable=true,margin=,selectedTextColor=,selectionColor=,kit=,typeHandlers=]
java.lang.Error
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:731)
    at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:761)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1016)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(JTextComponent.java:338)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:312)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:196)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JEditorPaneHtmlMarkupProcessor.convert(JEditorPaneHtmlMarkupProcessor.java:80)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.processMarkupText(JRFillTextElement.java:1018)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:546)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:488)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2067)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:788)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:298)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:152)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:649)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:971)
```

Despite the exceptions, the report is generated, but with two missing fields, both of which should be filled with the value of the same object property. And since I have two exceptions that are exactly the same, I suspect the exceptions are the reason these fields are missing.

I have checked the object passed to Jasper Reports and the property that fills the missing fields has a value, so I believe it's not a coding problem.

I know that it'd be easier if I put the content of the .jrxml file in here but it belongs to a client, so that will not be possible. Still, any help would be appreciated.

The application is an API running on Fuse Karaf 7.3.

Comment: No sure if it's the case but people are experiencing this kind of error when the JAVA run-time version mismatch. Try to check your development and production environments to see the JDK and JRE versions.

Comment: So far we only have a dev environment, as this is a new project. JDK version is 1.8.0_231.

Comment: I figured out that the exceptions where indeed connected to the two missing fields. The markup property was set to "html" in both of them, once I set it to "none", the fields were rendered. However, now other fields are being pushed to the right for some reason. Does anyone know why this is happening?